# How to show the price at the index (page home) in Indian Numbering System

Tags: django, python-3.6

here is my models.py file

```
class ProductPage(models.Model):

    item=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def price_tag(self):
      if price>=100000 or price<=9999999:
        price=price//100000
        return self.str(price)+ 'lac'
```

my view.py file.

def product(request):

```
object1=ProductPage.objects.all()
return render(request,'item.html',{'object1':object1})
```

and index.html file:

```
{% for i in object1 %}

           <tr> 
             <td>{{i.id}}</td>
             <td>{{i.item}}</td>
             <td>{{i.price_tag}}</td>
       {% endfor%}
```

In my admin panel price is in form of integer field i.e 10000. I want to convert it into a form as '1 lac' at the display page (see [Indian Numbering System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)). How to do that?

Comment: `if price>=100000 or price<=9999999` is true for any price below 10000000. Probably not what you mean. But what is it showing now?

Comment: if price>=100000 or price<=9999999  this line give me an error local variable 'price' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recommended Reading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-in-python-legb-rule/), [Recommended Reading 2](https://realpython.com/learning-paths/object-oriented-programming-oop-python/)

[Recommended Before doing more Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Your variable `price` will be resolved to the field declaration on the model. This isn't how things work in OOP and Django specifically. There's 4 mistakes in total, all corrected below. Try to figure out why:

```py
class Product(models.Model):

    item=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def price_tag(self):
      if self.price>=100000 and price<=9999999:
        price=price//100000
        return f"{self.price}lac"
      return str(self.price) if self.price is not None else ""
```